# changing src attributes <img>

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I have to parse the html of an email, get all the img tags and replace the src value with the url of the image I want.

This part is already done.  I can access the `<img>` and change the attribute with the url I want.

The problem is that when I print the html the src equals `cid:companylogo` and it should be the full url of the image I gave.

I need to know how to load the html after the src values of the `<img>` in the original html are changed. The below code receives as a parameter the original html of the email in a string which is "body"

```
        string SRC = "";
        int indice = 0;
        //Console.WriteLine(body);

        HtmlDocument email = new HtmlDocument();
        email.LoadHtml(body);

        foreach (HtmlNode img in email.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img"))
        {
            SRC = img.GetAttributeValue("src", null);
            for (int i = 0; i < contentIDS.Count; i++)
            {
                if (SRC.Equals(contentIDS[i]))
                {
                    indice = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            img.SetAttributeValue("src", urls[indice].ToString());//change src value
            Console.WriteLine("URL" + img.GetAttributeValue("src", null));//its printed how i want to
        }

        body = item.Body;//am stuck here i want body to have a final value of the whole html but with the changes made in src above.
        return body;
```

Comment: What is the `item` variable you are referring to in the line before the return?

Comment: its received also as a parameter the call to this function is inside this block: foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)

Comment: the point is i dont know how to access the html content that has suffer the change in the src values of the <img>

Comment: You are not changing `item` at all, but `email`. Why use the object you have not changed?

Comment: yes i see that, strange thing is there is no email.body in my documentation , i have the latest version of htmlagilitypack

Comment: Your last comment is the first time you mention the HTML Agility Pack. You really should have mentioned that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

As you note in your comments, the `item` variable you are using is also passed in - however, this isn't what you are manipulating.

Instead of:

```
body = item.Body;
```

You should use:

```
body = email.Body;
```

Update:

Since you have now revealed you are using the HAP, you can simply get the inner HTML of the document node.

Untested:

```
body = email.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: HtmlDocument objects as email is one of them does not have a .Body method in documentation

Comment: @rdk1992 - It's been there since version 2 of the framework. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.body.aspx

Comment: this stuff is crazy then as it not recognizes this method. I download the latest version of htmlagilitypack api

Comment: @rdk1992 - I was pointing to MSDN documentation, not HAP documentation.

Comment: would you be so kind to point me out the link so i can download that library :)

Comment: same problem img tags dont change their src value, weird thing is i know it has been change cause when i call the img.getattributesvalue i get the url i want the src value to take. But when i get the html it doesnt suffers this changes :(