# To parse the html of an email, get all the img tags and replace the src value with the url of the image I want.

Tags: parsing, c#-4.0, xhtml

I have to parse the html of an email, get all the img tags and replace the src value with the url of the image I want. 
I have got some code for this on following link:
[changing src attributes <img>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381701/changing-src-attributes-img)

but this is not working.
could somebody help me with this code?

Comment: What part of it is not working? Can you edit your post to contain what you have so far, and what errors you are getting? A jsfiddle would work well also.

Comment: I have just downloaded the htmlagilitypack and i am getting error in below line:(HtmlNode img in email.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img"))

Comment: Could someone give me code snippet to achieve what I need?

Comment: No. Post the lowest amount of code you can to reproduce it and people will help.